# How do I use the parameters of the object that I am calling a function on?

Tags: c++, function

```
//Function to find the distance between 2 points
TLength CPoint::Distance(const CPoint& point) const
{
    TLength horiz = abs(point.X() - OBJECT.X());
  TLength vert = abs(point.Y() - OBJECT.Y());
  TLength dist = sqrt(pow(horiz,2) + pow(vert,2)); 
  return dist;
};


int main()
{
const CPoint a = CPoint(4,5);
const CPoint b = CPoint(1,1);

a.Distance(b);

};
```

Is there a term i can use instead of OBJECT to be able to use the value of a in the function Distance?

Comment: Omg that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! Couldn't find it anywhere, I don't think I was asking the question right haha

Comment: Another thing, *always* use `std::abs` in case the C-style `abs` gets used which truncates the result (easy to do unless you've included the correct headers). And one more: use `horiz * horiz` rather than `pow(horiz, 2)`.

Comment: Thanks! @Bathsheba

Comment: @Rebekah There are TONS of questions on StackOverflow about what the `this` pointer is, and how to use it.

Comment: Thanks Remy, yeah I knew it was a common thing but because I couldnt remember the word "this" i was really struggling to search for it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is the pointer on self object, so

```
TLength CPoint::Distance(const CPoint& point) const
{
    TLength horiz = abs(point.X() - this->X());
    TLength vert = abs(point.Y() - this->Y());
    TLength dist = sqrt(pow(horiz, 2) + pow(vert,2)); 
    return dist;
}
```

And it is even "implicit" (unless required (dependent name, local name with same name as member, ...))

```
TLength CPoint::Distance(const CPoint& point) const
{
    TLength horiz = abs(point.X() - X());
    TLength vert = abs(point.Y() - Y());
    TLength dist = sqrt(pow(horiz, 2) + pow(vert,2)); 
    return dist;
}
```